# Hot-fix during the ongoing release - merge or cherry-pick?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-flow

We are trying to follow the git flow with SourceTree tool from Attlasian with all its magic buttons like: start/finish feature, start/finish release, start/finish hot-fix. So far so good, everything seems to be logical.

The tiny problem appears when we need to hot fix while we have an ongoing release branch.

So according to the git flow once we are done with the hot fix, the branch of the hot-fix is merged into master and into develop - so the SourceTree does. In [a-successful-git-branching-model document](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is clearly stated, that it is an exceptional situation and you need to merge the hot-fix branch into the master and into the release branch, later on this hot-fix will be merged back into develop.

My problem here is that I don't want to do this manual merging back and forth, I still want to use the magic buttons from the SourceTree tool.

So what options do I have:

1. Cherry picking the hot-fix commit from develop into release brunch - don't really like it, cause the history is missing
2. Merge the whole master branch into release branch - not even sure if it's a good idea
3. **?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what was my problem. The flow we were using wasn't a pure git-flow. According to the git-flow the next release is in *develop* branch, once it's stable and ready to be released, a short-living(a matter of minutes) *release* branch is created for "dotting the i's". Right afterwards this branch should be finished with merging it into *master* branch and into *develop*.
So, if we strictly follow the git-flow, there will never be a question "merge or cherry-pick during the ongoing release branch", cause there will be no situation like this.

Comment: Can you give a reference or more info about the sentence "a short-living(a matter of minutes) release branch"?

Comment: I'm not sure where @Max read that advice, but the original git flow article says the opposite: "This new [release] branch may exist there for a while, until the release may be rolled out definitely. During that time, bug fixes may be applied in this branch (rather than on the develop branch). Adding large new features here is strictly prohibited. They must be merged into develop, and therefore, wait for the next big release." https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 0):

Given that you closed your hotfix branch (and it was merged back into `develop` and `master`), if you don't want to cherry pick the commit, I would consider just merging `develop` branch into your `release` branch (have a look first at what else has happened on `develop` since you started the `release`branch)

If you want to do this exclusively via the magic buttons (no command line or manual merges) and are happy to bump another version number, you can just finish your release (merges onto master and also onto development, after your hotfix), and start a new release.

Comment: 1. I can't merge develop into release - develop is already different.
2. I can't finish the release yet - cause it needs to be retested after I introduce the hot-fix

So I guess the SourceTree tool is just not following the git-flow properly, hence I can not get a proper flow.

Comment: Well if that's the case then I think you have no choice but to cheery pick. This is really the situation that cherry-pick was designed for - so don't be afraid to use it.